# How can I create a group in SignalR with a user of whom I don't have the connectionId?

Tags: asp.net-core, signalr, chat

I looked around to see if the issue was already covered, but it appears that there are no good coverages for such situations, or that I was unable to find any.

So, I'm attempting to set up a private chat between two individuals. Currently, I can't create a group because I don't have the receiver's `connectionId`, which can only be obtained when the user joins the hub, but in any adequate chat application (say, Instagram), the sender selects the receiver, sends the message to them, and then the receiver chooses whether or not to join the chat.

So, I'm wondering whether there's another way to get the connectionId, and if not, what's the standard procedure for making such a chat?

Answer (score 0):

No, You can only get the `connectionId` after user joins the hub. Because in general, User even don't know his own `connectionId`. The SignalR Hubs API provides the `OnConnectedAsync` and `OnDisconnectedAsync` virtual methods to manage and track connections. You can create a mapping table between `name` and `connectionId` and save it in memory or any place you want. When user join the hub, Get the name and connectionid, Then override `OnConnectedAsync/OnDisconnectedAsync` to `add/remove` record about this mapping table. Finally, In your `Add group` method, you can get the `connectionId` by receiver's name in this mapping table.